# how does compiler handle optimizations for IF statement

Tags: c#, assembly, clr, compiler-optimization

I was reading a book that describes why `Volatile` is needed

```
class ThreadsSharingData {
   private Int32 m_flag = 0;
   private Int32 m_value = 0;

   // This method is executed by one thread
   public void Thread1() {
      // Note: These could execute in reverse order
      m_value = 5;
      m_flag = 1;
   }
   
   // This method is executed by another thread
   public void Thread2() {
      // Note: m_value could be read before m_flag
      if (m_flag == 1)
         Console.WriteLine(m_value);
   }
}
```

I get the point that using `Volatile` disables compiler optimizations such as reordering, and the book says:

> But even Thread1 method executes in program order (the way it was written), Thread2 method could still display 0. When compiling the code in the Thread2 method, the compiler must generate code to read m_flag and m_value from RAM into CPU registers. It is possible that RAM will deliver the value of m_value first, which would contain a 0. Then the Thread1 method could execute, changing m_value to 5 and m_flag to 1. But Thread2's CPU register doesn't see that m_value has been changed to 5 by this other thread, and then the value in m_flag could be read from RAM into a CPU register and the value of m_flag becomes 1 now, causing Thread2 to again display 0.

I don't get why "RAM can deliver the value of m_value first". If `m_flag` is not 1, then there is no need to load value into `m_value`, so `m_flag` should be delivered by RAM first, which is the correct logic,  isn't it?

and the description sounds like, no matter what the value of `m_flag` is, `m_value` will have to be read just in case `m_flag` is `1, which doesn't sound efficient becase reading value from RAM and save the value into a register can be costly, so why the compiler generate the assembly code that does possibile unnecessary reads? or what's the benefits to have unnecessary reads in advance?

Comment: As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2012/december/csharp-the-csharp-memory-model-in-theory-and-practice both reads and writes may be reordered by the compiler or cpu. That's how the theory of the memory model is defined. In practice, with the current compiler / JIT on current CPU's, these reorders may not occur.

Comment: Most of what you think you know about how programs execute is a lie. The OS and CPU pretend that memory and cpu behaviour, for single threaded programs, hasn't changed in the last 60 years. With memory swapping to disk, CPU memory caches, CPU speculative execution, etc both when a read request is issued by the CPU and when the response is received back, can vary considerably. At least compared to ancient computer designs where the CPU would pause until each read or write was complete.

Comment: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102376/0100/Memory-access-ordering

Comment: If they're in different cache lines, this can happen easily.  Branch prediction predicts that the `if` body should run, so it does (speculatively) before the first load completes.  If the `m_flag` load misses in cache but the `m_value` load hits in cache, the reading core can read that value first, before the `m_flag` load eventually completes, allowing execution of the branch instruction to confirm the prediction of that speculation.  See also https://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/

Comment: Also related: [C11 Standalone memory barriers LoadLoad StoreStore LoadStore StoreLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61710818) /  [Can a load or store be reordered before a conditional?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57937532)  / [What happens with nested branches and speculative execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59209662)